# SQL-Case When Issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to sort the transaction dates into an aging policy. When `LastDate` has been in the location for greater than `Aging Days` limit policy it should show up as `OverAge` if not `Within` referring to the current date.
Here is the current table:

```
+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|LastDate | Part | Location | Aging Days  |
+---------+------+----------+-------------+
12/1/2016   123    VVV          90
8/10/2017   444    RRR          10
8/01/2017   144    PR           21
7/15/2017   12     RRR          10
```

Here is the query:

```
select
q.lastdate, 
r.part, r.location,
a.agingpolicy as 'Aging Days'
  from opsintranexcel r (nolock)
left InventoryAging a (nolock) on r.location=a.location
left join (select part,MAX(trandate) as lastdate from opsintran group by 
    part) q on r.part=q.part
```

Here is the extra column I want added in:

```
+---------+------+----------+------------+---------+
|LastDate | Part | Location | Aging Days |   Age   |
+---------+------+----------+------------+---------+
 12/1/2016   123     VVV          90       Overage
 8/10/2017   444     RRR          10       Within 
 8/01/2017   144     PR           21       Within
 7/15/2017   12      RRR          10       Overage
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: You lost me at perpost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below code will be work for you

```
SELECT
  q.lastdate, 
  r.part, 
  r.location,
  a.agingpolicy as 'Aging Days'
  'Age' =
     CASE
       WHEN DATEDIFF( day, q.LastDate, GETDATE() ) > a.agingpolicy THEN 'Overage'
       ELSE THEN 'Within'
     END 
FROM opsintranexcel r (nolock)
LEFT JOIN InventoryAging a (nolock) on r.location=a.location
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT part,MAX(trandate) as lastdate 
    FROM opsintran 
    WHERE trantype='II' and PerPost>='201601' 
    GROUP BY part) q ON r.part=q.part
```

Comment: If your like , please press button as a true answer :))))).

Answer (score 1):

you can check the difference of the current date and the lastdate value if over or within the aging days

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), q.lastdate) > a.agingpolicy
     THEN 'Overage'
     ELSE 'Within'
 END AS age
```

Answer (score -1):

You should modify your query as:

```
select
q.lastdate, 
r.part, r.location,
a.agingpolicy as 'Aging Days',
if(DATEDIFF(NOW(), q.lastdate)) > a.agingpolicy, 'Overage','Within') as 'Age'
from opsintranexcel r (nolock)
left InventoryAging a (nolock) on r.location=a.location
left join (select part,MAX(trandate) as lastdate from opsintran  where 
    trantype='II' and PerPost>='201601' group by part) q on r.part=q.part
```